# h:selectOneMenu is not getting populated on f:ajax in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, selectonemenu

I am trying to populate a dropdown list when some other drop down gets changed its value. i.e. the popular example: country and city. I tried the f:ajax for this. well the ajax call is happening but the city dropdown is not getting populated.

There is some problem in my Managed Bean code itself, but I can't find it. Can someone take a look?

`register.xhtml`

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{registerBean.state}" required="true">                    
          <f:selectItems value="#{registerBean.stateList}"/>
       <f:ajax render="outputDrop city" listener="#{registerBean.cityListener}"/>                                                            
     </h:selectOneMenu>                    
                <h:message for="state" />

                <h:outputText id="outputDrop" value="#{registerBean.state}" />

                <h:outputText value="#{msgbundle.reg_city}" />
      <h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{registerBean.city}" required="true">
                   <f:selectItems value="#{registerBean.cityList}"  />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:message for="city" />
```

ManagedBean

```
package org.droidaceapps.contractortimeflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

public class RegUserInfoBean {
   private String userName;
   private String city;   
   private String state;
   private String phone;
   private String sex;

   private ArrayList<SelectItem> stateList;
   private ArrayList<SelectItem> cityList;

   private enum stateKeys {AP,TN,MH};

   public ArrayList<SelectItem> getStateList(){
       stateList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
   stateList.add(new SelectItem(null,"Select state"));
   stateList.add(new SelectItem("AP","Andhra Pradesh"));
   stateList.add(new SelectItem("TN","Tamilnadu"));
   stateList.add(new SelectItem("MH","Maharastra"));
   return stateList;
}

  public ArrayList<SelectItem> getCityList(){
   cityList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
   cityList.add(new SelectItem(null,"Select"));
   return cityList;
   }

  public void cityListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){

   switch(stateKeys.valueOf(state)){
   case AP:
          cityList.add(new SelectItem("VIJ","Vijayawada"));
          cityList.add(new SelectItem("GUN","Guntur"));           
          break;
   case MH:
          cityList.add(new SelectItem("MUM","Mumbai"));
          cityList.add(new SelectItem("PUN","Pune"));             
          break;
   case TN:
          cityList.add(new SelectItem("CHE","Chennai"));
          cityList.add(new SelectItem("MAD","Madurai"));              
          break;
    default:
        cityList.add(new SelectItem("NA","No value"));
   }

}


public String getSex() {
return sex;
 }
public void setSex(String sex) {
this.sex = sex;
 }
public String getUserName() {
return userName;
 }
 public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
public String getCity() {
return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
 }

 public String getState() {
return state;
 }
 public void setState(String state) {
this.state = state;
 }
public String getPhone() {
return phone;
 }
public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're recreating the citylist everytime in the getter method. You should not do that. The getter methods should **not** contain any business code. They should only return the property. You should be doing initialization in the constructor of the backing bean or a `@PostConstruct` method.

So, replace

```
public ArrayList<SelectItem> getCityList(){
    cityList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    cityList.add(new SelectItem(null,"Select"));
    return cityList;
}
```

by

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    cityList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    cityList.add(new SelectItem(null,"Select"));
}

public ArrayList<SelectItem> getCityList(){
    return cityList;
}
```

I'd also change the `getStateList()` method accordingly. Recreating the list on every getter method call is plain inefficient.

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did the initialization in very wrong way. I see all your answer BalusC and wonder how you got this much knowledge (almost in all java tech!!!)!!!!! ;-)